# Cannot push certain string into to an array

Tags: javascript

I am a newbie to javascript and made a mistake somewhere with the following code to find the string "Craig" and push it into a new array "Hits".

```
var text = "Hey, how are you \ doing? My name is Emily.\ My other friends       name is Craig. My friend Craig is learning JavaScript";
var myName = "Craig"
var hits = [];

for(var i = 0; i < text.length; i++){
if(text[i]=== "C"){
    for(var j = i; j < myName.length; j++ ){
       hits.push(j); 
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `for loop` condition is not correct. Replace it with below.
 Use `j < i + myName.length`

```
for(var j = i; j < i+myName.length; j++ )
```

PS:- There are better way to do this, `indexOf()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var text = "Hey, how are you \ doing? My name is Emily.\ My other    friends name is Craig. My friend Craig is learning JavaScript";

    var myName = "Craig"
    var hits = [];

    if (str.indexOf("Craig") > -1)
    {
       hits.push(myName);
    }
```

Here indexOf will return the position of the string match,if string is not found then the indexOf returns -1